# How can you modify clipboard text?

Tags: clipboard, copy-paste

Selecting and copying text off the page on the link below seems to lead to some text being automatically added. When this is pasted there is an extra line which starts off with "Read more:". How is this done?

[Article at Dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-111364/Can-stomach-acid-cause-bloating.html)

Comment: This appears to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400737/editing-clipboard-data-when-copying-pasting-from-a-website

Answer (score 1):

They've got a lot of Javascript on that page. I assume that they're intercepting the copy, and fiddling with it somehow.

Comment: It's the somehow I'm interested in. I've added a comment with a link above.